# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined REACTjs problem

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

This code constantly gives me error that cannot read property map of undefined, i am simply trying to fetch some data from the database

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state={
    products:[]
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getProducts();
  }

  getProducts = _ =>{
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/products')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => this.setState({products: response.data}))
      .catch(err=>console.error(err))
  }


  renderProduct=({product_id,name})=> <div key={product_id}>{name}</div>
  render() {
    const{products}=this.state;
    return (

      <div className="App">
        {products.map(this.renderProduct)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The server side send code

```
app.get('/products', function (req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM prod', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.send(results);
    });

});
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is in getProducts, you need to make sure response.data.products exists it might have another name. Check the `console.log(data)`.

```
  getProducts = _ =>{
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/products')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({products: data.products }) || console.log(data))
       // data is an object you need to pick the correct key
      .catch(err=>console.error(err))
  }
```

You should check whether there are any products available in the array.

```
render() {
    const{products}=this.state;
    return (

      <div className="App">
        {products.length ? products.map(this.renderProduct) : 'No products available'}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: the array is empty... but if I inspect and go to network the products are fetched infact in the response

Comment: What happens when you console.log(response.data)

Comment: it says 'undefined' on console

Comment: Use data instead of response its a promise so you dont need to reuse response twice

Comment: .then(({data}) => {
        console.log(data)
      })  did this still says undefined

Comment: why are you wrapping data in curly brackets, just do .then(data => console.log(data))

Comment: oh yes that helped... wrapping was causing the problem and as you said response is a promise i used 'data' instead of 'response.data'.... its working fine now.... THANK YOU SO MUCH for your help

Answer (score 0):

Is it likely that your CRUD in the database is returning a Null, Undefined value or the server send a object and not a array, which causes your state to be updated in the componetDidMount with data that is not an array, hence the problem?

Comment: server sends an array of json objects

Comment: It is possible that you can show the data in console how the data of repo.json () is and before doing the setState () ?. As mentioned @Omar

Comment: To seem your server is not returning correct data, could you update your question to see how you are sending the server data?

Comment: as i said before the data is being fetched.... like if i inspect and then go to network... there products are fetched